# Socket.io connection works only once

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, socket.io

I use [this](https://github.com/rikulo/socket.io-client-dart) library (socket.io) in my flutter app for instant messaging using web sockets.

There are 2 screens - `Home` and `Chat`. After a form input from `Home` screen, the app navigates to `Chat` screen, inside `initState()` method of which, I have written the code to establish the socket connection:

```
IO.Socket socket;
void initState() {
    socket = IO.io('http://localhost:3000', <String, dynamic>{
        'transports': ['websocket'],
        'query': {
            'timeStamp': new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch
        }
    });

    socket.on('connect', (_) {
         print("debug: connected");
    });
});
```

The connection works the first time I navigate from `Home` to `Chat`. But, If I navigate back to the `Home` page and then come back to `Chat`, the connection doesn't work. What could be the reason?

This is the code for navigating back to the `Home` page:

```
onPressed: () {
                socket.destroy();
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MyHomePage(),
                    ),
                    (x) => false);
              },
```

No action is done on socket inside the `dispose()` method of the widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because it tries to reuse the same socket for connections to the same host. The solution is to use `'force new connection': true` on connection.

```
socket = IO.io('http://localhost:3000', <String, dynamic>{
    'transports': ['websocket'],
    'force new connection': true,
    'query': {
         'timeStamp': new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice, this works for me.